# MVC Controller getting hit twice on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

My MVC Controller is getting hit twice on page load, and I am stumped on how to solve this problem.

I'm using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in my Layout page, and that passes the latitude and longitude to my controller.

I have `RenderAction` in a div, just in case the user has JavaScript disabled, as some people still do
:-(

This is what is causing my problem:
The `RenderAction` is getting rendered 1st and hitting the controller. Then, the AJAX request is firing and hitting the controller.

So my controller is getting hit twice per request.

Is there something I'm missing which will stop that, because at the moment, all I can think of is to remove the render action from the page.

**Code:**

```
<div class="dvWeather">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("PvCurrentWeatherConditions", "Weather"); }
</div> 

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // alert("Geo-Enabled");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var aj = "gl";

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("PvCurrentWeatherConditions", "Weather")',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            lat: lat,
            lon: lon,
            aj: aj
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('.dvWeather').html(result);
        }
    });
}

public PartialViewResult PvCurrentWeatherConditions(string lat, string lon, string aj)
{

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        try
        {
            //TODO create Viewmodel
            GeoCoordinate gc = new GeoCoordinate();
            var latitude = gc.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat);
            var longitude = gc.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lon);
            string latlon = latitude + "," + longitude;
            var displayCurrentConditions = _igcc.CurrentConditions(latlon);
            return PartialView("pvCurrentWeatherConditions");
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            //TODO get ip address
            return PartialView("pvLocationBasedOnIpAddress");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return PartialView("pvError");
        }
    }
    return PartialView("pvLocationBasedOnIpAddress");
}
```

Comment: Is this Spring MVC I am looking at? If yes, may I suggest changing the `MVC` tag to `spring-mvc` instead? That might help get more qualified answers.

Comment: Apart from that, how is `showPosition` executed when the page loads?

Comment: Hi @janfoeh added how showposition in code

Comment: @janfoeh no, it's not. Changed tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use another method for checking if the visitor has javascript disabled, like noscript:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="[URL]?java=off">
</noscript>
```

then handle the querystring in a new action.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to remove the Render action. Just make another (negative) check in the div:

```
<div class="dvWeather">
<script type="text/javascript>
    //if (!navigator.geolocation) { : Edit
      if (navigator.geolocation == null) {
        @{ Html.RenderAction("PvCurrentWeatherConditions", "Weather"); }
    }
</script>
</div>
```

Edit:

```
if (navigator.geolocation != null) {
            // alert("Geo-Enabled");
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
        }
```

This way only one call will be made.

Hope it helps.